# Can Metro style native app have same name for different CPU in Windows 8 Store?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, native-code

Assuming I'm programming in native (unmanaged) c++ and want to compile my application to x86, x64 and ARM:

1. How can I publish my application to Windows 8 store to support all three CPU architectures?
2. Can I publish 3 apps with same name but different CPU architecture?

Comment: Probably I would be the same as is now for Windows Phone. You have choose an option "for 7.0" or "7.5"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create an app package, you will have the option to choose what kind of CPU you want to support.

[image]

Comment: So it seems that I can publish one package/App with dlls compiled for all three CPU. Hope that Windows store will choose apropriate version when app will be installed on client machine. Thanks.